# How to chant ashttotar satnamavali?

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, yoga, kali

I want to know which is a better way to chant ashttotar satnamavali like all 108 names at one time by seeing a book,page or phone (coz obviously I can't remember every name line by line) or chanting one name 108 time a day so 108 names in 108 days

Comment: For any namavali first read it **completely** (all 108 names in one sitting)(from anywhere) till you byheart it then without seeing....prefer a physical book source though

Comment: @Rāmachandra what do you mean by without seeing do I have to memorize it also can I write 108 names in a page and then chant it

Comment: Yes you can do that keep reading and eventually in 1-2 months you would be able to recall from memory :)

Comment: @Rāmachandra OK thnks